# is there any way to validate the Android Advertising ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, google-advertising-id

I want to get a unique id from an Android Device, so as per the current best practice Google recommended way is Advertising ID, with all the permission i got the ID, now I want to send that into the backend and validate it, is there any special way to validate the Advertising ID ?

Comment: No.  It's a black box id.  Just accept it.  Really the only way it could be faked is if someone ran your app on a custom version of Android specifically overriding that functionality-  and there's just no value in doing so.  Unless you're trying to do something really stupid like use it as an account identifier (don't do that)

Comment: great thank you!